# Show message in div in submit form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, submit

I'm trying to show() a div whenever the user submits the form. The whole site is one page. Currently when you submit it, the form is submitted, then .confirmation div shows up for about 1 second and then it goes away, the page refreshes and the div is gone.

This is my HTML

```
    <form id="contactform" class="col s12 l6" action="mailer.php" method="post" >

      <div class="confirmation"><p>Thanks for contacting us. We will be in touch with you shortly.</p></div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input name="inputName" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="inputName">Name</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input name="inputEmail" type="email" class="validate">
          <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input name="inputPhone" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="inputPhone">Phone</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <textarea class="materialize-textarea" name="inputMessage"></textarea>
          <label>Message</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">

          <button id="submit-button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light cyan col s6" type="submit">Submit
            <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
          </button>

      </div>
    </form>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
.confirmation {
  display: none;
}
```

This is my PHP

```
    <?php
    /* Set e-mail recipient */
    $myemail = "krm218@gmail.com";

    /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
    $name = $_POST['inputName'];
    $email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
    $phone = $_POST['inputPhone'];
    /* $inquiry = $_POST['inputInquiry']; */
    $message = $_POST['inputMessage'];

    /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

    $subject = "Cleaning Services Contact or Estimate";

    $message = "

    Victorias Cleaning Services Contact Form

    Name: $name
    Email: $email
    Phone: $phone

    Message:
    $message

    ";

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

    /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
    header('Location: index.html#contact');

    exit();
    ?>
```

and a scripts.js file

```
$('#submit-button').click(function(){
    $(".confirmation").show();
});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: When you click submit, the form will send the form data to mailer.php, then show the result of that request to the user (reloading the page)
So any javascript/jquery that runs BEFORE the page reloads is irrelevant.
Try something like this in PHP instead:
`<div class="confirmation" style="<?php if(!isset($_POST)) echo 'display: none'; ?>">`
that way, you won't need the css either

Comment: I put that on the php form but the .confirmation div is now displaying in the browser since I took the css off. Can it be hidden at the beginning and show after the page reloads and form is submitted?

Comment: That is what should happen with my example...

Comment: The PHP i posted should be put into the html you posted at the top, and replace the opening tag of the confirmation div..

Comment: So I did that, http://victoriacleans.com/vc.com/index.html  
the contact part kind of broke.... The testimonials div was 100% before I put that in the html..?

Comment: The PHP isn't running on that page... http://i.imgur.com/cqWkdIm.png I'll post a javascript solution instead...

Comment: I thought I had accidentally messed up some css but it doesnt work when I send the form either. does the php file I have stay the same?

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm not very good with PHP and the form I created used PHP...

Comment: The form can be submitted without clicking the button, put the listener on the form's submit handler (though telling the user the form is being submitted when the browser already does that seems superfluous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in scripts.js:

```
$('#contactform button[type=submit]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.confirmation').show();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#contactform').submit();
  }, 5000);
});
```

5000 means it will show the message for 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds) then submit the form.

(All the other files can stay like they originally were)

Comment: You might want to check which div has the class 'confirmation', I'm not sure the HTML is the same on the website as it is in the example right now..

Comment: Ok I have made the changes and uploaded it

Comment: Looks like it's submitting but the div is still being affected by the css display: none; so it's not showing up

Comment: Look again at my code, i tweaked it a bit, if you update scripts.js with the code above it should work!

Comment: That did it!! Thank you so much!!! so to make it shorter id change it to 3000 or so.

Comment: yep, that should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

When the page refreshes, that is the form submitting. If you want it to be delayed, you can use preventDefault and window.setTimeout(), or you can send the form over AJAX and redirect the page later. Good luck!

Comment: I want to be able to have some sort of message to tell the user the form has been sent.. but it seems it's too fast? I can slow that down?

Comment: When the form submits, have it trigger Javascript that prevents the form's default action. Then, show your div, wait, and run document.forms[0].submit() to really submit the form.